# Is there such thing as a 'hyperphrase'?

Tags: terminology, phrases

In linguistics there is a common hierarchy of words:

```
Hypernym     (e.g. Colours)    
   |
   V
Hyponym     (e.g. Brown, yellow)
```

Does such a hierarchy exist within phrases?

Comment: Yes. They're called hypernyms. Words are just phrases without spaces. ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii I suppose, but doesn't the -nym bit just mean word?

Comment: Sure, that's its etymology, but etymology doesn't determine usage.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell, a hyperphrase is a convergence of speech, gesture, and gaze, and perhaps other signaling factors. So, my utterance + how I was gesturing at the time + where I was looking and when combine to convey a hyperphrastic message greater than just the words uttered. See https://books.google.co.il/books?id=edAGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=what+is+a+hyperphrase&source=bl&ots=dv0yrIM3jX&sig=ACfU3U3oH2Yu6_c6MWCUtiqQsOviw1LJsw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf68D3zpHkAhUzVBUIHWJ3CAQQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20a%20hyperphrase&f=false

Comment: That may be another use of the word "hyperphrase", but it's not what this question is asking about.

Comment: It's not too bad of an input to the question, but it just fails to outline what a hypophrase would be in contrast.